# Using weapons control on raiders

Tags: battlestar-galactica

I just played my first game of BSG (solo using the official fully cooperative rules). I've got the german edition so my card names might be a bit off...

In my version the "weapons control" locations says something like:

**Action:** Attack a cylon ship using the Galactica.

Is it possible to attack a raider or heavy raider with Galactica's guns? It doesn't say it has to be a basestar and in the show the Galactica is seen doing this IIRC...

I conceed that vipers are usually better suited for this job but what if:

- I'm out of vipers
- Raiders are about to attack a civilian ship an there's no viper to intercept them in time
- Or if I simply want to get a head start on those heavy raiders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right.  Just because the attack chart doesn't say what happens when Galactica attacks a raider or heavy raider, it doesn't mean galactica can't do it, just that the roll to hit is not different.  Blast away!

Comment: In the rules only galactica and the basestar specify who is shooting them on the attack chart. All others are assumed to be attacked the same way. If Galactica couldn't shoot them they would list with the vipers.